# How to filter part of view in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

[image]

I have a view in zend in which we have the form to submit entry and on bottom we have listed the previous entries. i have applied the search functionality and its working fine when we click on search button. Now what i want is to apply search on keyup event using getJSON event so we can instantly search the content.

I have added two condition for seach...for search using search button click.

```
  if($req->isPost()) {

        {
            //$ajaxPostedData = $req->getPost();
        $ajaxPostedData = $req->getParams();
        //echo $ajaxPostedData['search_term'];
        $select->where("ma_heading like '%".$ajaxPostedData['search_term']."%'");       
        //$select->where($val)
        //echo $select->__toString();die;
        //print_r($data = $db_model->fetchAll($select));
        //die;
        //echo $select->__toString();

        return $data = $db_model->fetchAll($select);

        # Paging section
        $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($data);
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(PAGING_RESULT_PER_PAGE);
        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
        $paginator->setPageRange(PAGING_PAGES_RANGE_PER_PAGE);
        $this->view->data = $paginator;
            //$this->_helper->P($ajaxPostedData);die;
            //


    }
```

and for keyup event

```
if($req->isXmlHttpRequest())
        {
            //$ajaxPostedData = $req->getPost();
        $ajaxPostedData = $req->getParams();
        //echo $ajaxPostedData['search_term'];
        $select->where("ma_heading like '%".$ajaxPostedData['search_term']."%'");       
        //$select->where($val)
        //echo $select->__toString();die;
        //print_r($data = $db_model->fetchAll($select));
        //die;
        //echo $select->__toString();

        return $data = $db_model->fetchAll($select);

        # Paging section
        $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($data);
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(PAGING_RESULT_PER_PAGE);
        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
        $paginator->setPageRange(PAGING_PAGES_RANGE_PER_PAGE);
        $this->view->data = $paginator;
            //$this->_helper->P($ajaxPostedData);die;
            //
        }
```

But the content is not replace dynamically when we are searching the content on keyup.

Please help me how can i apply keyup search in zend.

This is the jQuery script which i have used to send request

```
jQuery('#txt_heading_filer').keyup(function() {
        var heading = jQuery('#txt_heading_filer').val();

        $.getJSON('admin/admin/announcements/search_term/'+heading, function() {            

        });
    });
```

This is the table which need to refreshed on search

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="top-table-bg">
        <tr>
            <th width="" align="left"><?php echo $obj_trans->_('heading'); ?></th>
            <th width="20%" align="left"><?php echo $obj_trans->_('expiry date'); ?></th>
            <th width="10%" align="center"><?php echo $obj_trans->_('publish/unpublish'); ?></th>
            <th width="10%" align="center"><?php echo $obj_trans->_('action'); ?></th>
        </tr>
        <?php  
        foreach($data_arr as $key => $data) { ?>
        <tr>
          <td align="left" class="name" ><span><?php echo $data[PREFIX_MASTER_ANNOUNCEMENTS . 'heading']; ?></span></td>
          <td align="left" class="name">
          <?php echo (!empty($data[PREFIX_MASTER_ANNOUNCEMENTS . 'expiry_date'])) ? date("j", strtotime($data[PREFIX_MASTER_ANNOUNCEMENTS . 'expiry_date'])).'<sup>'.date("S", strtotime($data[PREFIX_MASTER_ANNOUNCEMENTS . 'expiry_date'])).'</sup> '.date("M, Y", strtotime($data[PREFIX_MASTER_ANNOUNCEMENTS . 'expiry_date'])) : "N/A"; ?>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
            <?php Admin_View_Helper_GeneralHelper::status_icon($data[PREFIX_MASTER_ANNOUNCEMENTS . 'status']); ?></td>
          <td align="center">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="info_tooltip update_data" title="Edit" rel="<?php echo $data[PREFIX_MASTER_ANNOUNCEMENTS . 'id']; ?>" id="link_edit"><?php echo $this->img("img/admin/icons/edit.png", array('id' => 'icon_edit')) ?></a>

            <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'announcements', 'do' => 'delete', 'item' => $data[PREFIX_MASTER_ANNOUNCEMENTS . 'id'])); ?>" class="info_tooltip delete_data" title="Delete" rel="<?php echo $data[PREFIX_MASTER_ANNOUNCEMENTS . 'id']; ?>" id=""><?php echo $this->img("img/admin/icons/delete.png", array('id' => 'icon_delete')) ?></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>

      </table>
```

Comment: can you show us your relevant `.phtml` and script

Comment: @NandakumarV i have added the jquery and view.ptml content ....please share your thoughs

Comment: There is form for entering data on the top of the page. Is the code for entering the data and the search in the same action?

Comment: Actually there is a entry form in above and list shown in the below.... In that list we have the search functionality

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is to sanitize those inputs to prevent SQL injection. Instead of `$select->where("ma_heading like '%".$ajaxPostedData['search_term']."%'")`, you probably want `$select->where("ma_heading like '%?%'", $ajaxPostedData['search_term'])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to put the table in a div with an id

```
<div  id='search-result-table'>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="top-table-bg">
        <!-- rows here -->
    </table>
</div>
```

Then on the js function, call the ajax and replace the contents in the div with the response

```
var heading = jQuery('#txt_heading_filer').val();
var url = 'admin/admin/announcements/search_term/'+heading;
$.get(url, function(data) {
  $('#search-result-table').html(data.result);
});
```

Then prepare the result. There is no need for the `if($req->isPost())` condition. You have to call the paginator for for all type of requests.

```
if($req->isXmlHttpRequest())
{
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(); //Disable view
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();    //Disable layout
    $html = $this->view->render('searchresult.phtml');  //Create a new view file in the script location and put the result (same code as in the view page) in it
    echo Zend_Json::encode(array('result'=>$html));     //Get the result and encode it
}
```

In `searchresult.phtml`:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="top-table-bg">
    <!-- rows here -->
</table>
```

Comment: You have to put the paging inside the div `search-result-table` and also in `searchresult.phtml`. So the paging view will also be updated along with the list.

Comment: Surely i will give this a try.The only concern is about paging because paging will redirect it to same controller

Comment: yeah,the paging used be ajax based that why i am bit confuse about this. or i have to add DataTables JQuery to show that grid

Comment: if you are not going to utilize the sorting, inline editing and other cool features in Jquery Datatables I recommend to use zend paginator

Comment: is there ajax paging available in zend ??

Comment: by default no.. but just changing the pagination.phtml can make it a ajax paination

Comment: Ok thanks a lot mate...it will be real helpful for me ... i will surely accept your answer soon..